# SelectOneButton "unselectable" attribute not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I don't want my SelectOneButton to be unselectable (clicking on a button twice). There supposedly is an attribute called "unselectable", which defaults to true, but setting it to false has no effect.

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{regulationBean.selection}" unselectable="false">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Maybe the attribute only works on a newer PrimeFaces version. Did you investigate that?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue with PrimeFaces 6.1. Switching to PrimeFaces 6.2 solved the problem. The `unselectable` attribute is correctly recognized now.

Answer (score 0):

Add primefaces latest version jar in your library . It will resolve the issue